# setVisibility not working within ViewFlipper

Tags: android, visibility, viewflipper

I'm trying to disable a TextView within a ViewFlipper via setVisibility to GONE and cannot get it to act like I'm wanting. My code:

```
switch(index) {        
    case 0:
        //Do Stuff
     findViewById(R.id.o2).setVisibility(8);
     findViewById(R.id.o3).setVisibility(8);
     break;
    case 1:
        //Do Stuff
     findViewById(R.id.o3).setVisibility(8);         
     break;
    case 2:
        //Do Stuff
     break;
    }
```

my XML

```
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/oFlipper"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:flipInterval="1000"
     android:inAnimation="@anim/push_up_in"
     android:outAnimation="@anim/push_up_out">
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:textSize="26sp"
         android:text="Opponents:"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/o1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:textSize="26sp"
         android:visibility="gone"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/o2"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:textSize="26sp"
         android:text="2"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/o3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:text="3"/>
 </ViewFlipper>
```

I've tried the code before and after .startFlipping() to no avail. It appears that the TextView is gone for one view flip and then reappears. But even when hardcoded to GONE in the XML file the view is simply blank rather than shifting the other views up in its place. I basically just want the TextView to go away completely. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: set the actual ViewFlipper to be gone?  I'm not sure I understand the question.  You can also use an onAnimationFinished listner (or something like that I forget the actual name) then set your view to be gone on that callback.

Comment: I essentially have a ViewFlipper of three different texts. Depending on the case chosen by the user. I want one or more of those texts to disappear and not be displayed. However, the "gone" attribute still leaves a blank space in the ViewFlipper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same issue.  Using `INVISIBLE` is better than `GONE`the view  is not displayed but it still takes up a timeslot e.g. you get the previous view for twice as long as you should.

I have got things working the way I want by adding and removing the child views from the ViewFlipper.  In the code where I was setting each sub view to `GONE`or `VISIBLE`(in onResume) I now remove them all from the flipper with .removeAllViews() then if I was setting them to visable I add them back in with .addView(mView);  It even looks to do the right thing when the ViewFlipper is empty.